# astropy CartesianRepresentation to NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray, astropy

I have an Astropy CartesianRepresentation object that looks like this:

```
<CartesianRepresentation (x, y, z) in km
    [(  4082.71516205,   248.89483863, -5882.92418597),
     (  5501.55728501,  2581.64039883, -5017.87534951), ...
```

I'd like to convert this to a NumPy ndarray so that individual elements can be indexed.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

considering your object name is "r" you could achieve that accessing r.x for the x component and r.y and r.z for the other components. You could also retrieve r.xyz.

Comment: Additionally, `CartesianRepresentation` and other `Representation` classes are already array-like.  You can access the first element in this case like `r[0]`.  See https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/coordinates/representations.html#array-values-and-numpy-array-method-analogs

Answer (score 0):

assuming `cart` is a `CartesianRepresentation`:

```
# both of these work
cartesian_ndarray = cart.xyz.value
cartesian_ndarray = np.array(cart.xyz.value)
```

For documentation, see the [xyz](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.coordinates.CartesianRepresentation.html#astropy.coordinates.CartesianRepresentation.xyz) attribute of the CartesianRepresentation class and its type [Quantity](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.units.Quantity.html#astropy.units.Quantity), who's base is a numpy array.

if `cart_diff` is a `CartesianDifferential`:

```
# both of these work
cartesian_ndarray = cart_diff.d_xyz.value
cartesian_ndarray = np.array(cart_diff.d_xyz.value)
```

For documentation, see the [d_xyz](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.coordinates.CartesianDifferential.html#astropy.coordinates.CartesianDifferential.d_xyz) attribute of the CartesianDifferential class and its type [Quantity](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.units.Quantity.html#astropy.units.Quantity), who's base is a numpy array.